# Undefined method 'rechercheprospect'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: symfony

I´m getting this error: Undefined method 'rechercheprospect'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

This is my ProspectRepository:

```
<?php
namespace Ass\AssurBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
* ProspectRepository
*
* This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
* repository methods below.
*/
class ProspectRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function rechercheprospect($type){

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p.nom, p.prenom,COUNT(c.idPros) as nb')
    ->from('AssAssurBundle:Prospect','p','AssAssurBundle:ComPros','c')
    ->where(p.type == $type)
    ->andWhere(p.id == c.idPros)
    ->andWhere(nb <3);
    $pros = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $pros;
}
}
```

This is My entity: Prospect

```
<?php

namespace Ass\AssurBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* Prospect
*
* @ORM\Table(name="prospect")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ass\AssurBundle\Entity\ProspectRepository")
*/
class Prospect
{
```

This my controller, where I call the repository:

```
$prosp = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getManager()
              ->getRepository("AssAssurBundle:Prospect")
              ->rechercheprospect('sante');
```

Any help ????
Thanks in advance

Comment: This means that the custom repository is not loaded. Have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: check what you have under repository object - `dump($this->getDoctrine()
              ->getManager()
              ->getRepository("AssAssurBundle:Prospect"));`

Comment: my version is symfony 2.3, dump don't exist

Comment: Check under Resources/config/doctrine and remove any mapping files you might find there.  They are interfering with your annotations.

Comment: There are no changes

Comment: check class like `print_r(get_class($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("AssAssurBundle:Prospect")))`

Comment: where i put this line??